# Conjectured primality test for numbers of the form $N=4 \cdot 3^n-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, counterexamples, elementary-proofs

This is a repost of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3205287/15660).

Can you provide proof or counterexample for the claim given below?

Inspired by [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . Let $N= 4 \cdot 3^{n}-1 $ where $n\ge3$ . Let $S_i=S_{i-1}^3-3  S_{i-1}$ with $S_0=P_9(6)$ . Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdi7EOwiAURXc-oxOvvkYBF0PfJ9iF3UHEQNICaYmmf9-3uDjdnHvvyWSsmOjam0celBWOdF_L7GN47lsMH3lDhQas8G0l3r8xzUEyjJQHjY7u5SX_FMOKO2vACSw_T6TYT2_piC5Y15Sb7DiW0MEPfVlq2VLjCuwBm0wsfQ==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

Numbers $n$ such that $4 \cdot 3^n-1$ is prime can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A005540) .

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
CE431(n1,n2)=
{
for(n=n1,n2,
N=4*3^n-1;
S=2*polchebyshev(9,1,3);
ctr=1;
while(ctr<=n-2,
S=Mod(2*polchebyshev(3,1,S/2),N);
ctr+=1);
if(S==0 && !ispseudoprime(N),print("n="n)))
}
```

P.S.

Partial answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3208094/15660).

Comment: Is this a partial case of https://mathoverflow.net/q/308886 ?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev No, it isn't. In post you mentioned we treat numbers of the form $N =k \cdot b^n-1$ with base $b$ being an even number not divisible by $3$ .